# Recommended max PHP session length

Tags: php, session

In terms of security (or other issues), what are the general recommendations / rules of thumb re PHP session length. A client with an Ecommerce website requested a 3day session length.

Comment: To keep a session 3 days active is maybe to long.
You could get in trouble with the memory.

Why don't you use a cookie?

Comment: This would mostly depend on what data you want to store in the "session". I would not suggest storing the login, however remembering who was last logged in is not usually a problem. Remembering their shopping cart shouldn't be a problem either. And this would be stored in cookie, not session.

Comment: The [OWASP Session Cheat Sheat](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet#Session_Expiration) has some useful information on session expiration.

Comment: With some visitors the browser might stay opened for days. So, what would be the recommended **max** PHP session length in this scenario? The relevant data stored in the session is shopping cart items.

Answer (score 2):

There are no general rule of thumb for this, depends on application build. For example:

1. For bank website: 15/30 Seconds might be appropriate
2. For a simple CMS application: 15 minutes long session is good enough.

Comment: if my bank timed me out after 15 seconds, I'd be switching banks...

Comment: The question is about **max**, not just "recommended" session length

Comment: @Vital, Haha, the question is hard to answer correctly on your terms.

Answer (score 0):

Personally for an ecommerce site I would be more worried about sessions being too short rather than too long. You can always force users to authenticate again before they are allowed to go to a billing page. This eliminates the possibility of someone stealing the session and buying whatever they want.